# Laravel in subfolder on webhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have a webapp written in Laravel that needs to run in a folder on a web host.
The app will have to be accessible via `hostname.com/webhit/`. This will point to the app's home page.

I only have one route:

```
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

HomeController's getIndex needs to serve the home page. **This works.**

However, as soon as I want to go to something like `hostname.com/webhit/login`, I get a 404 from Apache.

Obviously, `.htaccess` is not working properly. I need it to, essentially, turn URLs that look like `hostname.com/webhit/login` into `hostname.com/webhit/index.php/login`.

I have a `.htaccess` file in `www/webhit` (where `index.php` is located) that looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ webhit/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am not very familiar with `.htaccess` file syntax, but I believe it's doing something wrong.

### Edit:

I did it. My `.htaccess` was wrong (it actually causes a redirect loop), but the issue was that it wasn't even being parsed by Apache (hence the 404 instead of a 500 due to >10 redirects in a request). I did the following steps in order to get everything to work:

1. Enable `mod_rewrite` and restart Apache (plenty of docs out there on how to do this)
2. But wait, there's more! By default, Apache on Ubuntu prevents URL rewrites. [See this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles). Most importantly, the following fragment from the URL above is very important: "By **default**, Ubuntu's Apache will **ignore** the directives in your .htaccess files." You will need to actually enable rewrites by editing `\etc\apache2\sites-available\default` and setting AllowOverride to all (see link above for more details).
3. Reload the configuration (or just restart apache).
4. Make sure you're using the correct `.htaccess`. My original version actually has a redirect loop in it. See the selected response for the correct version.

After this, I got it to work. I hope it helps future programmers having a similar issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check default server requirements - laravel .htaccess file works for most situations. Try with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I would suggest you to use **resourceful** controllers - mappings from your route to your controllers methods are much more clear, and you'll get full
resource with one command (routes,models,views,controllers)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've tried the default laravel .htaccess too, but to no avail. I'll try this version as soon as I can and come back with more info. Also, I *am* using resourceful controllers! My home page is being processed within `getIndex()`.

Comment: I noticed that `mod_rewrite` was disabled. I enabled it (it's now shown when doing `print_r(apache_get_modules());die();`), restarted Apache, updated the `.htaccess` file and I still get 404 errors.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my question with the additional steps I took. I had to enable the module itself, and actually tell Apache to do the rewrites.